# How can I convert Python curves to a hair system?

Tags: python, particles

How can I get a set of curves defined in Python (list of Nx3 numpy arrays) imported to Blender as a hair particle system?

I assume there is a python API that I could use for creating a hair system like this, but I'm having trouble finding a reference to it..

Here's an example dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BweaCBovnNnFeThxWjJOcENwV1U

Comment: are you tried this addon https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Objects/HairNet ?   https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=241787&d=1371832949

Comment: This looks like there's a level of indirection with a guide-system, where I'd rather create the hairs directly. Looks like some python code that I should look at to understand though!